# Can I use a virtual machine to connect to a public WIFI to use Internet by totally isolating the host from it?

Tags: wifi, virtualization, internet, hardening

I want to use my laptop to connect to a public WiFi in a library but...

I have strong security in my Windows host machine (comodo firewall using a public network settings and rules, protocols disabled, limited privileges account, GPO rules, services disabledm, browser hardened with settings and extensions...) and use dnscrypt to help protecting my DNS but i think this wound't be enough to be totally safe if I connect my host to the wifi.

I have no VPN right now. Can I use virtual machine to connect an use only Internet through it and totally isolating the host system from the network?.

I have a Wifi usb dongle too. So i was thinking in disabling all the network interfaces in the host (including the VM one) and connect the VM (guest) only to that dongle.

What do you recommend, there is any guide out there to do this with Virtual Box?

This is only to browse the internet and maybe download some documents & programs, not to use my user credentials by loging in some web but I want to access my projects and documents in my host HDDs securely by isolanting it from the internet.

If I wanted only internet no HDD access I would use Tails u other Live OS and run, but... (I don't want to mount my HDD and browse the files in it while I'm connected to a not trustworthy network)

Comment: Which threats do you want to protect against? More and more traffic is moving over TLS these days, so in general I'm not **too** worried about public wifis any more. I was more worried ten years ago.

Comment: My thread is someone sniffing my traffic. I use dnscrypt so the HTTPS traffic would be protected against mitm in theory but i want to not take risks at all. I want to isolate my host for real to avoid any risk. Nowdays anybody can use xploits easily with kali or similar...

Comment: dnscrypt would not be the primary protection against MITM on TLS. Certificate validation and HSTS would be the primary protection. Obtaining a valid certificate is *difficult*, and HSTS prevents downgrade attacks. DNSSEC or similar only authenticates the results of lookups, and doesn't make MITM impossible if you control the network.

Comment: But if sniffing of traffic is a concern, no, a VM will not change that in any fashion.

Comment: Perhaps you should try editing or rewriting your question to make clear exactly what you want to protect yourself against. Your question uses the word 'securely', but your comment above indicates that your real concern isn't security so much as privacy. Since you want an answer focused on privacy, I would suggest you frame your question accordingly.

Comment: @vidarlo You are right. I use dnscrypt to add an extra layer to protect you against DNS spoofing by encrypting DNS queries. It has a different role than DNSSEC. It protects you against MITM/spoofing but not against cache poisoning like DNSSEC does. Certificates are other useful mechanism of protection (in a trusting way). By the way I use httpseverywhere and I disable untrusted encryption suites in my browsing client.

Comment: @Johnny My bad I explained quite bad in my first comment so I end up mixing things up.... I rephrase a I little bit my question. I want to totally isolate my host from the internet connection of the VM (guest) so I use only my VM for browsing (no private data or logings). It's a privacy reason too but security too. I do not want to some can access my host data from the VM conection. In other words, no queries/paclets from my host, no talking. But I use my host to access an open/read my personal documents/projects in public areas (right now I am not paying for VPN)

Comment: Computers do not *randomly* leak information onto a network. If the data is so sensitive that you don't trust being networked, I believe the solution would be separate hardware.

Answer (score 1):

> If I wanted only internet no HDD access.. I would use Tails and run, but...

You can use Tails on your computer and have a full access to your files and documents. Linux have evolved ;)
But honestly, I do not think you need this much of protection for browsing the Internet on a public WiFi :
Use HTTPS everywhere, have a well configured firewall and you should be alright, unless you're carrying with you strictly confidential documents, which I seriously doubt.

Also, a VM is not in anyway a mean to protect your host. There is [many ways to escape VMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine_escape), and the only purpose of such machines is to create an environment which is controlled, thus useful for security research, better separation of data, or retrocompatibility e.g.

To sum up, the only way for being secure on the Internet is to be careful : I frequently use McDonald's or Starbucks' WiFi and I do not have any Antivirus or Firewall on my Windows 10 laptop. What I have though is experience and most importantly the ability to not click anywhere.

Always update your system, check that you're using HTTPS and be careful with your DNS.

Comment: I know you can mount NTFS on Linux since a very long time ago. I am a Linux user too since many years but I get your comment since I didn't explain myself correctly (now I added an explanation at the end of my question). I am not carrying my super secret files but they are still personal (projects, notes...) so I want to keep them private. I added some comments to the other reply to reflect this too.  I know there are ways to scape from VMs but the odds are quite more minimal than connecting directly the host to internet. That kind of threads are for powerful or targeted people. Not my case

Comment: Caution doesn't protect you from many Internet attacks like DNS poisoning or MITM... and I am very careful. In your case an VPN connection would be the best protection. If you don't care about logging, no problem... for the DNS dnscrpypt is handy. One layer more.